# How to run the traceroute command in linux?

Tags: package-management, traceroute

My GCSE coursework in linux is asking me to do this:

[image: Stupid GCSE questions]

Whenever I attempt it it says this:

[image: It doesn't work]

So do I just need to install the packages and it will work?

Comment: I can't add the image for what happened once I installed it but basically this happened:

Comment: student@VS-STU-022:~$ traceroute bbc.co.uk
traceroute to bbc.co.uk (212.58.246.79), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets

 1  * * *
 2  172.19.175.253 (172.19.175.253)  0.215 ms  0.189 ms  0.166 ms
 3  213.235.26.97 (213.235.26.97)  1.978 ms  1.949 ms  1.871 ms
 4  213.235.42.202 (213.235.42.202)  3.105 ms  3.033 ms  3.013 ms
 5  xe-0-1-0.jprg-01.thn.uk.easynet.net (135.196.65.115)  3.198 ms  3.176 ms  3.146 ms
 6  * * *
 7  * * *
 8  * * *
 9  * * *
10  * * *
11  * * *
12  * * *
13  * * *
14  * * *
15  * * *
16  * * *
17  * * *
18  * * *
19  * * *
20  * * *

Comment: This is a normal output.

Comment: Can you explain it? I don't understand linux but we have to do it for 25% of our final grade and the teacher doesn't help

Comment: This is not a homework solution service.

Comment: And this is not homework. This is my GCSE and I'm asking for someone to assist me with linux.

Comment: In terminal, `man traceroute` will tell all.

Comment: This document may also be helpful, insofar as better enabling others to provide you the help you request: http://www.catb.org/esr/faqs/smart-questions.html

Answer (score 26):

The default command for this purpose in Ubuntu is `tracepath`.

However you can install `traceroute` too by running

```
sudo apt install traceroute
```

as you can see in the error message.

Comment: I did that but once I did and I tried to run it, it came up with something that basically got me stuck

Answer (score 5):

Install `traceroute` by using the following command :

```
sudo apt-get install inetutils-traceroute
```

However you can use the default command in linux which is `tracepath`, but it is not as flexible as `traceroute`. In `traceroute` we can choose between TCP, UDP, ICMP data formats and gives us ability to change some options. Thus it requires root privileges.

Comment: I don't see what this adds to [Pilot6 answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/844686/225694) since the question explicitly asks about `traceroute` it would seem `tracepath` is irrelevant to this question.